# Keep getting TypeError when attempting to plot a curve

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, typeerror

I'm trying trying to plot data from a csv file on my local drive and keep getting a TypeError on line 9 which says:
`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`
I've tried converting the variables to floats with no luck so not too sure where im going wrong

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
from math import log
# define the objective function

def objective(l, B, T, t):
    return l * log(B / (T - t))

# load the dataset
df = read_csv(r'pathoffile.csv', header=None)
data = df.values

# choose imput and output variables
T, L = data[1, 0], data[1, 1]

# curve fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, T, L)

# summarize parameter values
l, B, T, t = popt

# plot input vs output
pyplot.scatter(T, L)

# define a sequence of inputs between smallest and largest inputs
T_line = np.arange(min(T), max(T), 1)

# calculate the output for the range
L_line = objective(T_line, l, B, T, t)

# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(T_line, L_line, '--', color='red')
pyplot.show()
'''
```

Comment: The problem is that you KEEP doing the same thing!  Do you understand the problem?  For a `sequence` like a `list`, "multiply" means replicate, and only works with a integer.  Do you mean to use a list like that?  Or were you thinking of a numeric multiplication, such as with an array?

Comment: Assuming the error is in the `l * log(B / (T - t))` line (you should show full traceback), then `l` must be a 'sequence', not an array.  Which means we/you need to look a `T` and `L` that are given to `curve_fit`.  It may also help to add a debugging `print(l)` line to `objective`.  Since this code depends on reading a `csv` I cannot replicate the problem or do any testing.